# Not getting the correct output

Tags: c#

I have an input `string` as "thisIsMyNameNishant" and I want the output as
"this_Is_My_Name_Nishant". I want to solve this issue using Lambda expression.

I wrote the following code using lambda expression but I'm  not getting the right output.

```
string str = "thisIsMyNameNishant";
List<char> newlist = str.ToList();
IEnumerable<string> queryvalue = newlist.Select((x, y) =>
{
    if (x.ToString().ToUpper() == y.ToString().ToUpper())
    {

        return "_" + y.ToString();
    }
    else
    {

        return y.ToString();
    }
});

foreach (string c in queryvalue)
{
    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(c));
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: And what did you observe when you debugged this code?

Comment: I am getting the output as

0123456789101112131415161718
=== getting the index value==============

Comment: That's not debugging - you have to actually use the tools at your disposal to see what your code is doing (wrong). Also you should read the documentation of [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8), the way you are trying to use it makes no sense

Comment: It sounds like you figured out that that `y` is the index. That's a good start. But what did you want from `y` anyway? Seems to me you just want to look at each letter, and if it's a capital letter, stick an underscore in front of it. Have you figured out what `x` is?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first can try this without lambda:

```
string result = "";

for ( int index = 0; index < str.Length; index++ )
{
  if (char.IsUpper(str[index]) && index != 0)
    result += '_';
  result += str[index];
}

Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which I wrote using lambda

```
string str = "thisIsMyNameNishant";
            var queryvalue = str.Select(x =>
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(x))
                    return "_" + x.ToString();

                else
                    return x.ToString();
            });

            foreach (string c in queryvalue)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToString(c));
            }
```

When I read the definition of "Select" then I was clear about it.

Comment: Better but you have a problem if the first letter is upper: you will get `_This_Is_My_Name_Nishant`

Comment: Since `c` is a string already, there is no point in converting it to a string. Also, you can use a ternary operator: `var queryvalue = str.Select(x => char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString());`.

Comment: yes. You are right. In this case I can use the second parameter Y and can check for the first index. if index > 0, then only apply the logic which I have written. this I have already implemented using the code.